# Matlab alternative to eval for a large string

Tags: matlab, eval

I need to define a variable in matlab using a very long string lets call it S. S contains the result of a symbolic calculation and I want to use that result in my matlab code. S is too long to copy directly into the code so instead I read it from a file. I can evaluate the expression in S using eval and it works alright but it is really slow (It takes about 15 sec). I need to get the value of S for different values of the variables within it 1000s of times so I need a faster way to do this. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: For improved performance, you could implement eval as a MEX function.
Also, have a look at this: 
http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Comment: Yes I saw that page when I was trying to figure this out but I don't think any of those cases apply to what I am trying to do. Could you explain what a MEX function is? Thanks.

Comment: MEX functions are native code implementations of function like eval() in C/C++ or Fortran and can thus be highly optimized. Your main problem is that eval() is really slow, so you have to find a way to write an optimized version for your particular needs and then use this one from within Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is your main goal you can do several things.

- convert the expression to a script and call it from your function (speed improvement will depend on the expression)
- if the expression is relatively smooth function without singular points then you can precalculate it for several values of input parameters. Then you interpolate that table for the remaining points. Should be faster than 15 sec anyway.
- you can combine both ways with a draft/final switch in your code using interpolation for draft calculations and exact code for "final" run (possibly overnight ;o)